# Enumeration constant declaration vs. definition - C standard

Tags: c, language-lawyer, declaration, definition, c11

The C11 standard specifies in [section 6.7/5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7p5):

> C11 6.7/5
>
> A definition of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier
>   that:
>
> (...)
>
> — for an enumeration constant, is the (only) declaration of the
>   identifier;
>
> (...)

Does the wording of the above paragraph state that

1. A definition of an enumeration constant is a declaration that is the (only) declaration
2. A definition of an enumeration constant is the (only) declaration?

Comment: It means that you cannot declare an enumeration constant without also defining it.  It also means you can't forward declare enumeration constants.  However, scoping still applies so you could have: `enum { NAME1, NAME2 }; void function(void) { enum { NAME1 = 37, NAME2 = -57 }; … }`.

Answer (score 1):

It means that declaring an enumeration constant also defines it.

As a result, an enum constant cannot appear more than once in a scope within a translation unit.  For example, the code below is invalid as it redeclares an enum constant:

```
enum a {
    AAA,
    BBB
};

enum b {
    BBB,   // error, redeclaration
    CCC
};
```

Comment: So it's 2.? Because 1. would not make any sense.

Comment: @Sinushyperbolikus Correct.  Since there can be only one declaration (which is also the definition) it doesn't make sense to talk about multiple declarations.